# How exactly does the strong interaction decrease with distance?

Tags: particle-physics, standard-model, strong-force, gluons

So, we all know that the strong force asymptotes but the thing is I've never gotten a good description as to *why*

Can someone explain;

1. How the Strong force weakens ***with distance?*** I think I have got the least appreciable grasp on this one, can I think off it as the quarks "absorbing the gluon flux tube thus the less force they feel and at extremely close distances when this flux tube is so small that the quarks basically feel nothing?

Comment: If you are talking about asymptotic freedom (at small separation), why did you assign the “confinement” (at large separation) tag? Also, the phrase “with distance” means “with *increasing* distance”, not “with *decreasing* distance”.

Comment: @Ghoster that is quite strange. I think it's just automatic since I don't remember writing that tag? I'll change it irregardless.

Comment: Sorry, I see now in the edit history that you didn’t assign the “confinement” tag; a moderator did.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is apparently a misinterpreation of asymptotic freedom in QCD. The strong interaction does not decrease with (spatial) distance, but on the contrary, it increases with larger distance. As an example, the force between a quark $q$ and an antiquark $\bar{q}$ (mediated by the gluon field) increases so strongly that this $q \bar{q}$ pair is confined within a distance of only $\sim 10^{-15}\, \rm m$ forming a hadronic bound state (a meson, e.g. a pion).

Your confusion might have its origin in the fact that the coupling strength of QCD decreases with larger energies and increases with smaller energies, respectively (asymptotic freedom). But larger energies correspond to probing the interaction at smaller distances and vice versa!

Comment: Hey,so does the interaction strength stay const with a ‘section’ of the flux tube¿

Comment: @MikeMutethia  The proper treatment of the interaction of quarks and gluons in the confinfinement region (i.e. at small distances) is a difficult and largely unsolved problem. Simple models like the flux tube picture, etc. should be taken with a grain of salt (especially in popularized presentations).

Comment: Hmm. I think that's a bit odd since I have come across many sources saying that quarks close together essentially don't feel each other. It was on Wilczek's paper report to he Nobel committee

Comment: Small distance = large energy = small force (see my answer)